# valid ics file is not a valid internet calendar file

Tags: php, outlook, icalendar

I've written a php script which produces an ics file output:

> BEGIN:VCALENDAR
>  PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN
>   VERSION:2.0
>  BEGIN:VEVENT
>  DTSTAMP:20120801T000000Z
>   DTSTART:20120801T000000Z
>  DTEND:20120801T000000Z
>   SUMMARY:test
>  ORGANIZER:Me
>  UID:Me
>  END:VEVENT
>   END:VCALENDAR

The file is shown to be valid when using the online validator:

http://severinghaus.org/projects/icv/

Now here's the strange thing.... If I opt to open the file as it is generated by the php I get the MS Outlook error message  is not a valid internet calendar file. But, if I open it from the folder it's created in, it gets imported without trouble.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Are you sending the appropriate headers when echoing out the content?

Answer (score 0):

As josh has noted, it is probably incorrect headers:

eg: ics file generated from wordpress plugin has:

```
header('Content-Type: text/calendar; charset=' . get_option('blog_charset').';');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="ical.ics"');
```

Comment: Thanks for that - I get the same issue whether I run the php script locally on my windows 7 machine or remotely on my linux platform. I also tried changing the headers: header('Content-Type: text/calendar; charset=UTF-8;');header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="ical.ics"');  ... no joy ..